# Specifying Constraints on a field representing a Date in an entity JPA

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I have to set a constraint over the fields "heureFin" & "heureDebut"  of my entity Intervention, I wonder how to precise this constraint : heureFin>heureDebut ??
here is my entity :

```
public class Intervention implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "IdIntervention", length = 50)
    private String idIntervention;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "HeureDebut", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date heureDebut;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "HeureFin", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date heureFin;
}
```

Is it possible, or should I process this constraint somewhere else ?

Thank you in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at member level. You should use **class level constraints** and implementing your own constraint validator (which takes an instance as parameter of its isValid() method, facilitating the comparison).

Create your custom validator:

```
public class HourRangeValidator implements Constraint<InterventionHourRange, Intervention> {
```

and implement `isValid` method with the comparison logic you need.

Create a custom annotation:

```
@ConstraintValidator(HourRangeValidator.class)
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface InterventionHourRange {
    String message() default "{your.error.message}";
    String[] groups() default {};
}
```

And annote your entity:

```
@InterventionHourRange
public class Intervention implements Serializable {
```

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html

Comment: Thank you Nicolas for Help :)